# Entity Framework Migrations with POCO's that Inherit not receiving parent attributes

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have the following setup for some POCO's with EF 4.2...

```
public class BaseItem
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The name of this item.
    /// </summary>
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [DisplayName("Name")]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Movie : BaseItem
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Using EF Migrations, I ran Add-Migration FirstDatabaseCreate and got the following migration...

```
CreateTable(
"Movie",
    c => new
    {
        Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
        Name = c.String(nullable: false)
        Description = c.String(),

    })
.PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
```

Notice that there is no **maxLength: 255** on the Name field in the migration script, even though I have **MaxLength** set on the BaseItem.

Is this a bug in Migrations or am I missing something else?

Comment: Can you show your context code? Are you using the latest version of migrations?